# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Reviews', 'Consumer_Feedback'

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert json to csv. But I get the error:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Reviews', 'Consumer_Feedback'
```

How to check that all keys are written?

This is what I've writen:

```
file_id = ''

    with open(filename_jsonl, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read():
            file_id += line

    file_id = [json.loads(item + '\n}') for item in file_id.split('}\n')[0:-1]]

    with open(filename_csv, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, file_id[0].keys(), delimiter=";")
        writer.writeheader()

        for profile in file_id:
            writer.writerow(profile)
```

jsonl

```js
{
  "First_and_Last_Name": "Lori Anderson",
  "Primary_Specialty": "Acupuncturist",
  "Practice": null,
  "Education": [],
  "Phone": "(405) 943-0377",
  "Address": "5701 NW 23rd St, Oklahoma City, OK  73127"
}
{
  "First_and_Last_Name": "Joe Wojciechowski, D.C.",
  "Primary_Specialty": "Chiropractor",
  "Practice": "13",
  "Education": [
    "Palmer College of Chiropractic"],
  "Consumer_Feedback": "(1 Review)",
  "Reviews": [
    "\r\nDr. Joe is an amazing chiropractor. He continues to educate himself and incorporates everything he learns into his practice."],
  "Phone": "(405) 878-6611",
  "Address": "18877 Ferdondo Dr., Earlsboro, OK  74840"
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a small sample of your JSON file (enough to recreate the problem)

Comment: Your first record contains fewer headings than the second one. This is used to determine the column headings. You might need to parse the file twice, first to create a list of fieldnames to pass to your `DictWriter(....fieldnames=...)`